# Elasticsearch exact search query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm using `query string` to search on documents in my index.

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "query_string": {
          "query": "table test",
          "default_field": "table.name",
          "default_operator":"AND"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

the problem is that it returns all additional strings that include search keywords.. I wanna to give strings that have exact phrase.
for example the documents `table test 1` and `table test 12` and `table test` are in my index. when I search `table test`, I wanna it just return `table test`.

I used `term` also, but it could not consider space charter between strings!

how can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mapping is generated by Elasticsearch, than for every text field there will be a corresponding `.keyword` field and hence

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "table.name.kwyword": { // Note .keyword in the field name.
        "value": "table test",
        "boost": 1.0
      }
    }
  }
```

if you don't have a `.keyword` field, then you have to create a `keyword` field and use `term` query that is used for `exact` or `keyword` searches.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but It does not work.. It return `table test 1` and `table test 12` too!

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri updated my answer, take a look and let me know if you have defined your mapping or Elasticsearch generated it

Comment: Elasticsearch generated the mapping.. your answer (without `keyword`) works for a word but it does not work for multi word with `space` like `table test`

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri great if Elasticsearch generated mapping, can you use the (query with `.keyword`) it should work on multi words as well

Comment: yes.. you are wright.. thank you a lot.

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri glad i was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Match Phrase Query as Amit suggested in another answer.

Also, if you want to use only Query String type of query then you can give your query in double quotes as shown below:

```json
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "query_string": {
          "query": "\"table test\"",
          "default_field": "table.name",
          "default_operator":"AND"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

**Updated:**

if you want to do exact match in entire field then you can go ahead with term query in elasticsearch:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "table.name.keyword": {
        "value": "table test",
        "boost": 1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but It does not work.. It return `table test 1` and `table test 12` too!

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Just know that in this case, the casing (lowercase / uppercase) will also play a role, i.e. `Table test` will not match `table test`

Comment: unfortunately, it returns nothing! it do not consider space between words!

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri As Amit mentioned, you need to use `.keyword`

Comment: please, rate my question :)